# why hiv genome not attacked by lysosome in macrophage

Tags: hiv

HIV cells lifecycle in macrophages suggests the early phase with naked genome entering the macrophage along with reverse trancriptase enzyme. i am thinking that macrophages are abundant with lysosomes and so called defense sodiers of the body who engulf all pathogens and kill them with lysosome action.

```
My questions
```

my question is that why this soldier is not able to distinguish a foreign and rather weird kind of genome of a retrovirus and not sending lysosome to act upon it at the very moment of entry of genome.

My second question is that why do T LYMPHOCYTES undergo lysis but macrophages are not affected?